# Viewing Python code for ArcGIS tool MakeVehicleRoutingProblemLayer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, vehicle-routing-problem

Is it possible to view the Python code for the [Make Vehicle Routing Problem Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/make-vehicle-routing-problem-layer.htm) tool of ArcGIS Desktop?

---

Actually I'm not looking for the Python code, I want to realize about the algorithm applied for solving VRP in GIS. Is it genetic algorithm, Integer programming or etc?

Answer (score 4):

No it is not possible. The Make Vehicle Routing Problem Layer tool is not a python script tool, it is a proprietary closed source binary/compiled tool.

You can see at a glance what sort a tool is from the icon in Toolbox:

- [image: binary/compiled tool] = binary/compiled tool
- [image: script tool] = script tool
- [image: model tool] = model tool

The [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/algorithms-used-by-network-analyst.htm#GUID-1043F777-C4BD-4F41-B708-1835A20FBFCC) states that "*The heuristics used in this process are based on a tabu search metaheuristic and are proprietary*". You may wish to look for an [open-source Vehicle Routing Problem solver](https://www.google.com/search?q=open-source%20Vehicle%20Routing%20Problem%20solver&oq=open-source%20Vehicle%20Routing%20Problem%20solver).